# JsonTransformation using Jolt

Tags: jolt

I'm using jolt + java(https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) to transform an external JSON in a format that I can understand.

My problem is the structure keeps changing and this is making my spec more and more complex.

I want to extract all the fields which are called "path" no matter the structure.

does someone have an idea how can I do that?

Example of structure:

```
{
    "groups": {
        "rows": {
            "fieldSets": {
                "fields": [{
                    "path": "example"
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}

or 

{
    "groups": {
        "rows": {
            "rowsets": {
                "fieldSets": {
                    "fields": [{
                        "path": "example"
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

or 
{
    "groups": {
        "fieldSets": {
            "fields": [{
                "path": "example"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

in the end, I just want an array with plain "path" values.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to the JOLT. Anyway I tried with what I understood from your question. Just try the below spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "groups": {
        "rows": {
          "fieldSets": {
            "fields": {
              "*": {
                "path": "path"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

If it is not what you are expecting, then please give an output json, so that i can understood what you want.